Mediapipe face mesh doesn't detect the face when it is cropped(just the face) using bounding box generated via mediaipipe
So i have been trying to detect and crop the face using mediapipe facemesh landmark points to calculate a bounding box .But when I ran the cropped image through the mediapipe it doesn't detect the face at all for some images.
Can anybody explain why is it happening ?
I was under the impression that if the same face is detected by mediapipe that it should give the same detection results after cropping it using the same mediapipe model.
Thanks in advance

i solved this problem by detecting face  then add the 25% margin before append to the crop_face and make the other prerpocessing on  and this is the function
def preprocess_image(image, input_size, detector):
    original_image = image.copy()
    img_res = detector.detectFaces(original_image)

    if len(img_res.boxes) > 0:
        bbox = img_res.boxes[0]  # Get لاbox
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
        x1 = int(x1 * image.shape[1])
        x2 = int(x2 * image.shape[1])
        y1 = int(y1 * image.shape[0])-28
        y2 = int(y2 * image.shape[0])+28

        # Adding  margin
        w = x2 - x1
        h = y2 - y1
        margin_h = int(0.25 * h)
        margin_w = int(0.25 * w)

        y1 = max(0, y1 - margin_h)
        y2 = min(original_image.shape[0], y2 + margin_h)
        x1 = max(0, x1 - margin_w)
        x2 = min(original_image.shape[1], x2 + margin_w)
        
        extended_image = original_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]

        if extended_image.size == 0:
            print("Extended crop results in empty image. Check bounding box and margin calculations.")
            return None, original_image, None

        # Resize the extended image to the input size required by the model
        image = cv2.resize(extended_image, input_size)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = image.astype(np.float32)
        image = (image - 127.5) / 127.5  # Normalize the image (0,1)
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        return image, original_image, (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return None, original_image, None


Hey  edries thanks for the response , i had tried doing this earlier but it didn't solve the problem for all the face images that i have . idk if it has something to do with how mediaipe was trained or is is it something else.
